# Remove external ip address from gke application with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

After [getting Prometheus up for a gke cluster](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/prometheus/README.md), I ran the step to add an external ip address for Grafana:

```
kubectl patch svc "prometheus-1-grafana" --namespace "cluster-1" \
  -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'
```

but now no longer want Grafana to be available via an external ip.

I've tried running with `-p '{"spec": {"type": "ClusterIP"}}'` but I just get the error:

```
The Service "prometheus-1-prometheus" is invalid: 
spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when
`type` is 'ClusterIP'
```

How do I do the above `kubectl patch svc` command to remove the external ip?

Comment: you can edit svc by running ```kubectl edit svc <name> -n <namespace>``` and replase ```NodePort``` with ```ClusterIP``` and remove ```nodePort``` from ```spec.ports[0]``` and save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the service to `LoadBalancer`, a `NodePort` is attributed to the service.

In order to return to `ClusterIP` you need to also remove the `NodePort`.

- Using `kubectl patch` we will set the `NodePort` to `NULL`, here is the command:

```
kubectl patch svc "prometheus-1-grafana" --namespace "cluster-1" --type="merge" \
-p '{"spec":{"ports":[{"nodePort":null,"port":<PORT_NUMBER>}],"type":"ClusterIP"}}'
```

**Note:** Kubernetes will not allow you to set the `nodePort` to `null` alone, because the `Port` field is obligatory, make sure to check the correct port and change it, I'm using an http server as example.

- Optionally, you can create a `patch.yaml`:

```
spec:
  ports:
  - port: <PORT_NUMBER>
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: <TARGET_PORT_NUMBER>
  type: ClusterIP
```

and Apply it:

```
kubectl patch svc "prometheus-1-grafana" --namespace "cluster-1" \
--type="merge" --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)"
```

---

**Reproduction:**

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
echo-svc     ClusterIP   10.0.13.9    <none>        80/TCP    65m

$ kubectl patch svc "echo-svc" -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'                                                                
service/echo-svc patched

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
echo-svc     LoadBalancer   10.0.13.9    <pending>     80:32021/TCP   65m

$ kubectl patch svc "echo-svc" --type="merge" -p '{"spec":{"ports":[{"nodePort":null,"port":80}],"type":"ClusterIP"}}'
service/echo-svc patched

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
echo-svc     ClusterIP   10.0.13.9    <none>        80/TCP    66m

$ kubectl patch svc "echo-svc" -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'                                                                
service/echo-svc patched

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
echo-svc     LoadBalancer   10.0.13.9    35.223.145.193   80:30394/TCP   66m

$ cat patch.yaml 
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP

$ kubectl patch svc "echo-svc" --type="merge" --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)"                                                             
service/echo-svc patched

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
echo-svc     ClusterIP   10.0.13.9    <none>        80/TCP    66m
```

**References:**

- [Json Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/)
- [Update API Object with Kubectl Patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)